# Loading in a new drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, operating-systems, window

I have a standard 1TB HDD in my computer right now that everything (including the Windows OS) is on. I want to purchase a SSD, install Windows on there and make that my primary drive. However, I want to keep all my music, pictures, etc on the HDD (because it's a lot and it's pointless to put it on the SSD). So I was wondering how to go about that. I know how to install the OS on the SSD, but then how do I keep the HDD connected without having the computer look at it to boot the OS off of.

Essentially, how do I make the SSD my primary without removing anything from my HDD? Or is there a way to remove the OS from my HDD (WITHOUT removing any of my important files like music, pictures, etc) so that the computer only looks at the SSD for the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out your old harddrive, put in  the SSD and install windows. Turn off the machine and install the HDD back in. On boot up, go into the BIOS and tell the computer to boot from the SSD. That should be it.

Comment: when you said go into BIOS, would I go into the boot settings and set the SSD to master drive or something?

Comment: As the computer starts to boot, press DELETE or F2 or F10 or whatever to get into the BIOS setup. Somewhere in there should be an option to set which drive should be the boot drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than half your drive available, Add a partition to your existing drive then move the non-OS files to the new partition.

If you have less than half your drive available, then create a new partition using 90% +/- of the free space, and move as many files as you can to the new partition freeing up space on the original partition.  Then enlarged the partition and move more files.  Do this until your have moved as many files as you would like.

After that, it becomes a simple partition copy, that is copy the OS partition (now smaller) to the new drive in its entirety.